# Multiple NICs and Gateway CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

CentOS 6.6

```
eth0
IPADDR=10.0.0.100
IPADDR2=10.0.0.101
GATEWAY=10.0.0.250
NETMASK=255.255.0.0

eth1
IPADDR=10.120.0.100
GATEWAY=10.120.0.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

Gateway on eth0 has Internet access but gateway on eth1 does not. I'm trying to ping IP address 10.58.1.100 which will work on only across eth1.

How do I accomplish this? I've tried creating manual routes with metric settings but it still doesn't work. On a windows machine I just have both NICs added, set static IPs and it all works fine.

If I do `ifdown eth0` then I can ping 10.58.1.100 no problem.

Comment: can you show us netstat -r ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the gateway setting on eth1. That means 'default gateway', i.e. a gateway which can reach the internet, which you said that one is not. You can add manual routes for the networks which that gateway *can* reach.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  eth0 has internet access and eth1 does not. eth1 is the interface that can access 10.58.1.100 but i still need Internet access.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused there for a moment. Edited the answer to fix.

Answer (score 0):

assuming router to `10.58.1.100` is `10.120.0.1`, you need to

```
 route add net 10.58.1.0/24 10.120.0.1 1
```

to add route dynamicaly.

for change to be permanent, edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1` add

```
10.58.1.0/24 via 10.120.0.1 dev eth1
```